# Interpreting Java Garbage Collection log summary

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand what does this summary means.

"eden space 116544K, 100% used" -> Does this mean that the eden space is 100% used throughout(average) the execution of the program, or the eden space is 100% when the program exit/complete execution.

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen total 233024K, used 116544K [0x00000000eaab0000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
 eden space 116544K, 100% used [0x00000000eaab0000,0x00000000f1c80000,0x00000000f1c80000)
 from space 116480K, 0% used [0x00000000f1c80000,0x00000000f1c80000,0x00000000f8e40000)
 to space 116480K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e40000,0x00000000f8e40000,0x0000000100000000)
 PSOldGen total 699072K, used 699071K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eaab0000, 0x00000000eaab0000)
 object space 699072K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaafff0,0x00000000eaab0000)
 PSPermGen total 21248K, used 2409K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bc2c0000, 0x00000000c0000000)
 object space 21248K, 11% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bb05a740,0x00000000bc2c0000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `100%` at the precise time this was logged, not on average, no. It might change to whatever percentage at *the very next* minor collection, and if you have further logs, you might be able to see that.

Comment: so how do you calculate the average usage of the young gen and old generation?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything I am not aware of averages being calculated and provided but the GC logging, there might be tools that do that; but an average is well not that hard to compute once you have the logs, I guess